# DataFrame doesn't display time when hours and minutes are zero?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

Is there an option to make pandas DataFrame display the full date and time even if HHMMSS are zero?

For example, the time of `dt.datetime(2020, 2, 14, 0, 0)` is not displayed, while the other is:

```
pd.DataFrame([{'earliest_time': dt.datetime(2020, 2, 14, 0, 0),'latest_time': dt.datetime(2020, 2, 14, 0, 15)}])
```

[image]

It doesn't change if 0 seconds are added. (These datetimes were converted from MySQL which somehow drops the seconds field)

Comment: Now, this is interesting `df = pd.DataFrame({'earliest_time': [dt.datetime(2020, 2, 14, 0, 0),dt.datetime(2020, 2, 14, 0, 1)],'latest_time': [dt.datetime(2020, 2, 14, 0, 15), dt.datetime(2020, 2, 14, 0, 15)]})` it will show the 00:00 in the series.

Comment: @ScottBoston, yet, not if the 2nd `earliest_time` HHMM are also zero `dt.datetime(2020, 2, 14, 0, 0)`